# Cannot find an initializer for type in swift

Tags: swift

```
struct PhoneP {
    var name = "Un-Name"
    var pphone = "Un-Phone"
    let NumOfDay = ""
    let date :NSDate = NSDate()
}

class PhoneManager: NSObject {

    var phones = [PhoneP]()

    func addPhone(name: String, phone: String, Nday: String){
        phones.append(PhoneP(name: name, pphone: phone, NumDay: Nday ,date: NSData()))
        //phones.append(Phone(name: name, pphone: phone, NumOfDay: Nday, date: NSDate()))
}
```

> error: swift:28:23: Cannot find an initializer for type 'Phone' that accepts an argument list of type '(name: String, pphone: String, NumOfDay: String, date: NSDate)'

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

`numOfDay` and `date` are constants which you already set. You won't be able to change them afterwards. Just use:

```
PhoneP(name: "name", pphone: "phone")
```

Or change your struct to:

```
struct PhoneP {
    var name = "Un-Name"
    var pphone = "Un-Phone"
    let NumOfDay: String
    let date: NSDate
}
```

You can then create the struct like:

```
PhoneP(name: "name", pphone: "phone", NumOfDay: "day", date: NSDate())
```

Also, you're adding `NSData()` to the type of `NSDate`, so that won't compile as well.

```
phones.append(PhoneP(name: name, pphone: phone, NumDay: Nday ,date: NSData()))
```